# How to use wildcard route in league/route in Lazy Loading way

Tags: php

I am using league/route 4.2.
I am trying to implement a lazy loading controller using wildcard.

```
class Router
{
    private $container;
    private $router;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->container = new Container();
        $this->router = new \League\Route\Router();
        $this->mapRouters();
        $this->dispatch();
    }

    private function mapRouters() {
        $this->router->map('GET', '/', [MainController::class, 'index']);
        //$this->router->map('GET', 'Main', 'Nanitelink\Module\Main\MainController::index');
        $this->router->map('GET', '{module}', 'Nanitelink\Module\{module}\{module}Controller::index');
    }

    private function dispatch() {
        $request = $this->container->get('Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest');
        $response = $this->router->dispatch($request);
        $emitter = $this->container->get('Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter');
        $emitter->emit($response);
    }
}
```

Now I know for a fact that the commented route works.
I tried to replace it with wildcard, but probably I am not getting the syntax correctly, but it throws following exception.

> Class 'Nanitelink\Module\{module}\{module}Controller' not found

What is the right way to use wildcard routing in league/route?
Documentation does not explain how to use wildcard in lazy loading way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the discussion on github with the package manager.

https://github.com/thephpleague/route/issues/247

So to keep the answer short, the package does not and will not allow the requirement to replace the callable to be named using variables matched to the wildcard.

I did suggest a source code change in github, if anyone need the information.